# EF 7 Query on parent entity with multiple children

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Thanks in advance for any help with this. We have been playing around a little with EF7 and ASP .Net 5.0 (Core 1.0?) and ran into the following roadblock.

I have an Application Model that has multiple properties and child entities. For the purpose of this question there are 2 children entities: ApplicationFuncArea and ApplicationLocation (relationship models because its a many to many relationship).

The parent class:

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string Hardware { get; set; }
    public string Documentation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationLocation> AppLocations {a get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationFuncArea> AppFuncAreas { get; set; }
    public Employee SolutionArchitect { get; set; }
    public bool IsInHouseApp { get; set; }

}
```

The child entities are very simple:

```
public class ApplicationFuncArea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public Application App { get; set; }

    public int FuncAreaId { get; set; }
    public FuncArea FuncArea { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public Application App { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

The Application class is the parent class that has ICollections of the 2 classes above as properties like so:

```
    ...

    public ICollection<ApplicationLocation> AppLocations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationFuncArea> AppFuncAreas { get; set; }

    ...
```

Ultimately we are trying to pull a list of all Applications in the parent table where LocId (from child ApplicationLocation entity) and FuncAreaId (from child ApplicationFuncArea entity) are equal to a specific value.

i had originally thought that this could work:

```
            return _context.Apps
            .Include(a => a.AppFuncAreas)
            .Include(a => a.AppLocations)
            .Where(a => a.AppFuncAreas.Any(fa => fa.FuncAreaId == FuncAreaId) && (a.AppLocations.Any(l => l.LocationId == LocId)));
```

however it is throwing the following implicit conversion error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Linq.IQueryable<AtlasAppPortfolio.Models.Application>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<AtlasAppPortfolio.Models.Application>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

seems like it should be easy but I cant seem to figure out what.

Comment: Please show how are the entities configured and the exact exception thrown

Comment: updated the original question with the details requested - hope that helps clarify a bit more.

Comment: Depending on the return value of your method it might be as simple as adding .ToList() after your where statement.

Comment: your "Where" statement looks odd and wrong if you asked me... by looking at it i would expect and exception... does it work if you take the where out... if it does... then please work on how you use your where statements.

Comment: A linq where clause returns a `System.Linq.IQueryable` value. You have to cast this with the return type you want, like `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback everyone... adding the ToList (duh!) fixed the exception however i am getting a new exception with the format of my Where as seabizkit anticipated. it is a runtime error:

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

any thoughts on building a multi condition where on children properties ?

Comment: I also tried this and got the same error:

'return _context.Apps
                .Include(a => a.AppFuncAreas)
                .Include(a => a.AppLocations)
                .Where(a => a.AppFuncAreas.Any(fa => fa.FuncAreaId == FuncAreaId))
                .Where(a => a.AppLocations.Any(l => l.LocationId == LocId))
                .ToList();'

Comment: @Seabizkit i think i figured it out... but not sure this is the right way to execute multiple where conditions on child entities... i added a `.ToList()` after the first `.Where()` clause and it worked... any thoughts ?

Comment: @quashBox yeah you shouldn't do it that way. As you are making the compiler try and work out what you mean and well it fails as it cant make that kind of magic*. Also writing it that way makes it actually quite hard to read. i.e. I would gladly show you how i would do it, if it started off as a readable format, please Include what you would write as SQL and i will write the linq version for you. Also this isn't IE7 specific its 4-7. I learn how to write some of my linq with a free tool called linqpad. Its worth checking out. I use it when it complicated and want to ensure its what i want

Comment: Thanks i will give LinqPad a try... i think the SQL statement should look something like this:

`select *
from Application
INNER JOIN ApplicationLocation ON (Application.Id = ApplicationLocation.AppId)
INNER JOIN ApplicationFuncArea ON (Application.Id = ApplicationFuncArea.AppId)
WHERE (ApplicationLocation.LocationId = 1)
AND (ApplicationFuncArea.FuncAreaId = 1)`

joining 2 child tables on the parent and filtering based on 2 conditions one for each child table

Comment: @Seabizkit - any thoughts on turning my query into linq (other than the one with 2 `.ToList()` ? thanks again for the assistance

Comment: @quashBox hey i have been looking into this but seem to be going in cycles trying to understand usage .... as i think it would be easier to do nothing on the where for the navigation props and just filter(where) the App... would that work? OR are you wanting a list of Apps back? Also many records are we talking about here... does it matter.. i mean I take it we dont need to get crazy as performance will be really fast anyway.

Comment: Hi Also please include code for Application.. i want to see the Nav properties.

Comment: @Seabizkit - ok i added parent class to the question above (cut out some properties for the sake of space and simplicity). Essenitally i need to query for a list of Applications based on its functional area and location meeting a certain criteria (matching IDs). The issue is the location ID and funcarea ID are in the child class (relationship models i included above). so i need a linq query that queries a list of apps that meet 2 criteria - 1 for each child. does that help clarify ?